# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib' - file ignored, no matter what i link

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, bjam

I have just `bjam`ed boost and it seems like its still gonna refuse to work (I alread have tried and given up to make this library). What I did was, that I launched bjam.exe and I linked:

> **include directories:** C:\ ... \boost_1_53_0
>   **Library directories:** C:\ ... \boost_1_53_0\bin.v2\libs

But I still get the error. So I decided to look in the folders, and this showed up to be path to the desired library:

> C:\ ... \boost_1_53_0\bin.v2\libs\date_time\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi\

If I explicitly add this folder to the **Library directories**, the library **is found** but in VCC another error pops up, asking me for another library.
So how do I ask bjam to make a **folder system that VCC can understand**?

Comment: After adding this long path folders one by one, I achieved to compile the application. But there are many libraries! There must be other way...

Comment: If you have followed the ["getting started"](http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/windows.html#invoke-b2) guide, the folder you need to add is "C:\...\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib".

Comment: Man. I did this of course. But after this taking no effect, I decided to try it manually.

Comment: I generate a Visual Studio Project using CMake (with FIND... Boost, and related include lib_directory) and still receive this error.

Answer (score 6):

Adding the C:...\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib directory worked for me. Added to:

Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following link to 'Configuration properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories ' helped me as well.
'C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib'