# Boost: fatal error LNK1104 when linking a lib named by bjam

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost

We use `bjam` to build the `boost` libs with the following parameters

```
  bjam --prefix=.\vs2012\x86\static --includedir=.\include --build-dir=.\build\vs2012\x86 --layout=system --build-type=minimal --without-mpi --without-python toolset=msvc-11.0 variant=release threading=multi link=static runtime-link=shared define=_BIND_TO_CURRENT_VCLIBS_VERSION address-model=32 install
```

So the lib names looks like `libboost_unit_test_framework.lib`. But when build the project I get `fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-1_53.lib'`
Well, I tried almost every solution for the linking issue LNK1104 e.g. suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398392/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-date-time-vc100-mt-gd-1-53-lib), but nothing helps. Do you have any ideas what is going wrong? Here my test code

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyClass test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include "myclass.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Calc_Test)
{
  MyClass* c = new MyClass();
  BOOST_CHECK(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `--layout=system` which builds without the tags on the build results. And when you use the headers you don't disable the auto-link feature (by defining `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`). Either:

1. Remove the `--layout=system` option, or
2. Disable auto-link by defining `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` and manually add the *.lib files to your link.

Comment: Thank you, specially for the 1. option. I'm going to revise the build batch.

Answer (score 0):

You have boost auto-linking enabled.

Use the following define to disable this option: `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`.

See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/more/getting_started.html#auto-link) more information on the topic.