# Building log4cplus for Windows x64

Tags: c++, windows, bash, makefile, log4cplus

I am supposed to build existing Windows 32bit project for Windows 64bit. (and probably linux 64bit too).

The project uses `log4cplus` library. That one only contains 32bit .lib files at the moment and is shining example of why I hate using libraries in C++ - there's just a bunch of source files and linux bash scripts. The `INSTALL` help file is entirely about the `configure` bash script which doesn't work on Windows. The `configure` probably just passes some arguments to GCC, but I don't known which ones.

I downloaded MinGW in hope I'll be able to use `mingw32-make` on the project and it will work, but no such thing happened.

So does anyone have any experience making those Linux projects on Windows? This is not the first time I tackle this problem - my third most viewed question is about [broken Boost build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15398392/607407). Judging from the view count, I'm not the only one who has problems building Linux project on widnows.

Comment: If I look at the [log4cplus GIT](https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus) it does have `CMake` support (which would give you the possibility to build a 64bit version with MinGW on windows). Is it an option to update to a newer version of `log4cplus`?

Comment: Ok, as browsing the GIT I noticed `msvc14` folder. Local library has similar folder with lower number, `msvc8`. This folder contains everything needed for Windows builds.

Comment: Glad to hear it's solved. I didn't see the `msvc` folder myself. You like to add an answer on how you got it solved?

Comment: I'll add answer with images later on, first I need to get the project running. For every solved linker error, ten more pops up. Now I'm stuck with boost again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

log4cplus maintainer here.

The `master` branch of log4cplug GIT repository is C++11 only. Because of this, it requires Visual Studio 2015 and thus the `msvc14` directory is there.

Branch [`1.2.x`](https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/tree/1.2.x) and its releases come with Visual Studio project files for version 2010. However, you might be able to build it using CMake for even older Visual Studio.

However, both of them, in any configuration, should have no problem building for AMD64 platform.

I also suggest that you read the [README.md](https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/blob/1.2.x/README.md) file. It documents many things, some of which might be useful to you, too.