# Where am I supposed to get b2.exe and bjam.exe everyone else uses to build boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I have (again) problems with boost library, specifically with zlib/iostreams part, which is due (again) [errors in that release of boost](https://tlzprgmr.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/building-boost-1-42-with-zlib-1-2-4-support/) - there were some changes in zlib library which didn't reflect to that boost release.

I wasn't the only one to have that problem but I seem to be the only one who doesn't know what is that `bjam.exe` everyone talks about as if it was built-in command on windows. Apparently, [I myself used that command in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15398392/607407), but that's 2 years ago.

I tried this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-jam/3.1.18/ but all I got was more cursed sourcecode.

So where did I get it? Where can I get it now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run either `bootstrap.sh` or `bootstrap.bat` depending on your OS first (you can also run it with `--help` key for a parameter list in case you want to make any adjustments in the configuration, but for a default build running it without any parameters at all works fine). It will configure boost for building and create `b2` and `bjam`.

Comment: Thanks, `bjam.exe` indeed appeared in the folder. `b2` did not, but all I've seen so far suggests these are same programs.

Comment: Then you are using a very old version of boost, @TomášZato. Why don't you actually use the Getting Started guide from that version, if you must? (e.g. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/index.html for the latest version)

Comment: I was dropped into compiling someone else's project. I didn't chose my libraries or project structure. Many of my problems were solved by maning up and migrating to newer boost version.